# GRUB dual boot menu fails to load specifically after shutting down from Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown

I am dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 but am having a sporadic issue.

GRUB will show up, and if I boot into Ubuntu, it works fine. If I shut down from Ubuntu and restart, everything works great.

However, *after I boot into Windows 10, shut down, and reboot*, the GRUB menu does NOT appear. Instead I am greeted with the Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported message:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
completions of a device/filename.
```

The only way for me to temporarily fix this issue is if I boot Ubuntu from my USB stick and run the boot repair. It claims it has fixed the boot menu/GRUB, but the process above continuously repeats. Booting into either OS works, but specifically after shutting down from Windows 10, the Minimal Bash message appears.

I tried this command from Windows 10 but it does not appear to have changed anything:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

I am booting in UEFI mode with SecureBoot mode disabled and have an Acer Aspire V7-582P-6673 if that helps.

Comment: Have you set "trust" in UEFI for /efi/ubuntu .efi boot files? All Acers seem to need that. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Some older threads mention downgrading UEFI, others says newest from Acer works. So make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the live session, on the USB or cd, to reinstall grub-efi. Open a terminal and enter the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt

Replace the hashtag in /dev/sda# with the number representing the partition where you had Ubuntu 16.04 installed. You can use gparted to do it.
sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt/boot/efi

Replace the hashtag in /dev/sda# with the number representing the efi partition. It's usually /dev/sda2.
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo mount -o bind /run /mnt/run

sudo chroot /mnt/

sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi

sudo update-grub
```

**reboot**, to realize if it works.